# Sync voice memos for the first time

Tags: itunes, windows, voice-memo

I recorded a long and important voice-memo on my old iPhone which is not synced anymore to any iTunes. I wanted to retrieve the memo using [the advice here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44914/21946), however choosing Sync Music in iTunes brought up this warning:

[image]

I tried to click Sync Music and the capacity bar at the bottom indeed indicated that all music, and presumably the voice memos too, would be deleted next time I sync the iPhone (the blue Audio bar was completely gone). I immediately reverted.

**How can I retrieve the voice memos?**

The other options in the question linked above include:

- DropVox - which costs money and forces me to have a DropBox account
- Macroplant iExplorer - which is a freeware that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this way of syncing. You can also manually update songs if you don't want to lose songs.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6403/iphone-transfer-voice-memos-from-iphone-to-computer/

Another option would be to email them to yourself.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, Easley! Can you please summarize the contents of the link you posted. Links have a tendency to disappear over time, leaving a non-answer for those who may find this down the road. Thank you!

Comment: The email option is best, but if you have lots of memos, get a program to archive / save them. On OS X, I recommend HoneView by ecamm.